# Shell Script Searching for String in *.aspx site using Curl

Tags: php, bash, shell, curl, raspbian

I am deliberately trying to write a simple script which permanently checks a Website for a certain string and sends an Email as soon as the page gets updated and contains the string.

I managed most of the task so far, only it doesn't work on my intended website. (Works on simple ones though).

I figured it might have to do with Cookies or JavaScript.

Heres my Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME="username"
PASSWORD="passwd"
URL="https://tickets.fcbayern.com/internetverkauf/EventList.aspx"
#!/bin/bash
echo "before"
for (( ; ; ));
do
    count=`curl -s "https://tickets.fcbayern.com/internetverkauf/EventList.aspx" | grep -c "Ausverkauft"`
    if [ "$count" != "0" ]
    then
echo "Found Text"
        sendEmail -f $USERNAME -s smtp.gmail.com:587 \
            -xu $USERNAME -xp $PASSWORD -t $USERNAME \
            -o tls=yes -u "Web page changed" \
            -m "Visit it at $URL"
       sleep 5
    fi
    echo "ende"
done
```

The intention is to check if

- the site contains "Ausverkauft" or "sold out" (english version)
- then send an email
- if not repeat check after 5 seconds

Would be amazing if you could help me.

Testing the script on simple sites worked fine!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? What do you get when you run just `curl "https://tickets.fcbayern.com/internetverkauf/EventList.aspx"`?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the target page requires cookies or does a forwarding to another page. The problem specified is that it cannot find the search string because it forwards to a different page when using CURL. Background is that i want to check when new tickets for Bayern matches go online. So if I take the curl output I receive:



<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/internetverkauf/TestForCookies.aspx?redirect=https%3a%2f%2ftickets.fcbayern.com%2finternetverkauf%2fEventList.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>